# XSLT substring-after last separator

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

How to make XSLT substring-after last separator

for example the separator is '-'

ex : N1-N2-N3

so the result should be N3

Comment: If your processor supports the EXSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function, you could use that with a `[last()]` predicate.

Comment: i dont have str:tokenize 
iam using XSLT 1.0

Comment: I know you are using XSLT 1.0 - you have tagged your question so. But some XSLT 1.0 processors support *extension* functions (read: extending the functionality of XSLT 1.0). Which processor are you using?